# Display: inline-block, after minimizing to certain width, stop inline-block and leave structure as is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to accomplish is:
After minimizing browser to certain width, 600px in my fiddle's case, stop the css rule: ***display: inline-block*** from making my container boxes from becoming 1 column.  I would like it to stay at 2 columns.

Additional notes: I am using jQuery plugin: Mixitup.

This is an example of the jQuery plugin's code, but not MY code as it is much larger than this:
http://codepen.io/jzhang172/pen/EVGNqj

---

What I tried doing:
Using ***CSS rule @media all (max-width:600px)***
I tried messing with the ***display: "value"***, but no good.  I figured the answer will be a javascript solution but I'm no expert at Javascript.

Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/886mbLbq/

```css
.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
    display:inline-block;
    
}

@media all and (max-width:600px)
    {
     #container .box{
      display:block;   
     }
        
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    
    
    
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep them in no less than 2 columns, set a min width on the container.

Sample 1: The extra 4 in 404px is to make up for inline elements extra margin (white space). You can read more about that here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Sample 2: If you don't want to use the inline-block hack, use floats. The extra `box-sizing: border-box;` is for making the temporary border I added for visibility, to stay within the `box` width/height

Flex would of course be a third way (no sample of that here though/yet).

Using inline-block:

```css
#container {
    min-width: 404px;   
}

.box{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
    display:inline-block;        
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>    
</div>
```

Using floats:

```css
#container, .box {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

#container {
    min-width: 400px;   
}

.box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: The 4px inline block hack is very, very unreliable and is not a cross browser fix.

Comment: @NickSalloum If you read this, https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/, you'll see it works from IE8 and cross browser.

Comment: @NickSalloum Now I also added a float version, so if you downvoted prior to give me a chance to reply, you might consider remove that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using floats instead of inline-block. This way you could target every element 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. element to start a new "line" with a clear. Here is an example of the CSS:

```
.box{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:black;
margin-right: 4px; /*or whatever you want; this is your spacing*/
margin-bottom: 4px;
float: left;

}

@media all and (max-width:600px)
{
 .box:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: left; 
   background:red; /*I put this here just so you could see which one...*/
   /*...is getting the clear. Get rid of it when ready. */ 
 }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/326bby8x/